# Get a substring from each text line

Tags: python

I have a text file with following lines:

```
User Input: "Hello"...................<1sec> 
User Input: "Hi!".....................<2sec>
User Input: "How's it going"..........<1sec>
```

I just want the strings in the ""

for now I am using,

```
m= ""
for line in file:
     if "USER INPUT" in lines :
         m+=line[12:]
```

I am not sure as to how to get the position of " to make sure its only between the two "".

Comment: have you tried using find? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/string_find.htm, you can just start the array after the first " and do a splice, ej: line[12:line.find(", 13)]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re
s = """User Input: "Hello"...................<1sec> 
User Input: "Hi!".....................<2sec>
User Input: "How's it going"..........<1sec>"""

for line in s.splitlines():
    if "User Input:" in line:
        m = re.search(r'\"(?P<data>.*?)\"', line)     #Get content between ""
        if m:
            print(m.group("data"))
```

**Output:**

```
Hello
Hi!
How's it going
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the lines on the `"` character to get a list of all elements on any side of said character. IDLE example:

```
>>> s = """User Input: "Hello"...................<1sec> 
User Input: "Hi!".....................<2sec>
User Input: "How's it going"..........<1sec>"""

>>> for line in s.splitlines():
    try:
        print(line.split('"')[1])
    except IndexError:
        pass


Hello
Hi!
How's it going
```

Comment: this will give list index out of range error if there is no `"` character in the line

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using findall:

```
import re

s = """User Input: "Hello"...................<1sec> 
User Input: "Hi!".....................<2sec>
User Input: "How's it going"..........<1sec>"""

for line in s.splitlines():

  output = re.findall(r'"([^"]*)"', line)
  if output:
    print(output[0])
```

Output:

```
Hello
Hi!
How's it going
```